# scala Instantiate case class for yield

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, case-class, for-comprehension

I was wondering if there is a way to instantiate a case class directly from a for comprehension (in this case im using the scalaz validation functor) without having to manually feed in the parameters from the for comprehension

If you have a case class like this

```
  case class Rawr(id:Option[Long],int:Int)
```

And then assuming you do something like this

```
  val test = for {
    none <- None.successNel
    anotherVariable <- 3.successNel
  } yield Rawr.apply _ //This doesn't work, just here to make it compile. 
  // I want to instantiate a Rawr automatically with the variables
  // in the for comprehension instead of having to manually put in
  // none and anotherVariable
```

So I can finally use it like this

```
  test match {
    case Success(p) => {
      //Should get a case class instance here i.e. p = Rawr(None,3)
    }
  }
```

The problem is, I am not getting a case class instance for p (obviously p is incorrect since I just used apply).

The reason why I am asking this, is that I have for comprehensions that provide 20+ variables, and having to feed in each variable to the case class instantiation creates a lot of boilerplate

Comment: I've got a blog post with a discussion of some alternatives (including _applicative builder_ syntax, which would be your best bet if you didn't have so many fields) [here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/05/applicative-validation-syntax/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will evaluate if these things are needed

It seems though, this honestly should be a problem that Scala should provide a standardized solution for, and not something that should be needed in the shapeless or scalaz libraries. The use case for mapping the result of a for comprehension to instantiate a class is quite common (i.e. rest web servers)

Comment: Awesome blog post @TravisBrown

Comment: @mdedetrich: A couple of points. Using a `for`-comprehension on `Validation`—which isn't a monad—isn't likely to do what you want (i.e., it won't accumulate errors). The standard library _kind of_ acknowledges that functors and monads exist, but doesn't provide any explicit support or syntax for applicative functors, which is what you need here. I don't think we're likely to see this kind of lifting operation in the standard library anytime soon.

Comment: @TravisBrown Yes I realize that it doesn't do what I need it to do (hence the reason for this question), I was simply tying to say that this behavior is common enough that Scala should provide its own syntax helper for it (just like we use for currently which is syntactic sugar for hiding nested flatMaps)